# Apache caching with mod_headers mod_expires

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm working on homework for uni and was hoping someone could clarify something for me. I need to set up the following:

- Configure the response header "Cache-Control" to have a "max-age" value of 7 days since access for all image files
- Configure the response header "Cache-Control" to have a "max-age" value of 5 days since modification for all static HTML files.
- Configure the response header "Cache-Control" to have a value of "public" for all static HTML and image files.
- Configure the response header "Cache-Control" to have a value of "private" for all PHP files.

My question is whether it is better to use a FilesMatch, or the mod_expires ExpiresByType to best achieve this? I've so far used the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
    ExpiresDefault "modification plus 5 days"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the

ExpiresActive On

directive wherever you want to apply `Expires` headers, for example

```
<Location / >    
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"    
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"    
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"

   ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 5 days"

   <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">        
      Header set Cache-Control "public"    
   </FilesMatch>

   <FilesMatch "\.(html)$">        
      Header set Cache-Control "public"    
   </FilesMatch>

   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "private"    
   </FilesMatch> 
</Location>
```

Comment: Ah right. Thanks Dave. I was close! I had set the ExpiresActive On, so things were working. What's the difference between using ExpiresDefault like I had in the FilesMatch and ExpiresByType as a separate line like you have? I didn't do that originally as it seemed like I was repeating myself

Comment: No real different, I prefer to have all my config actions inside a <Location /> block, but it's probably more a style thing than anything else

Comment: My version of Apache (2.2.15) complains: FilesMatch> cannot occur within <Location> section.  Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just in case anybody stumbles upon it...

There is a difference in using the FilesMatch and ExpiresByType directives.

FilesMatch matches a file by it's extension.

ExpiresByType matches a file by it's mime type.

It's generally better to use ExpiresByType.

Source http://www.websiteoptimization.com/secrets/advanced/caching-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd use ExpiresByType globally instead of ExpiresDefault in a context (FilesMatch).

Have you tested your configuration?

Comment: hmm, no. My text/html seems to have expired 15 days ago ... so if i use ExpiresByType, say, like this:

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 days" can I just add in public or private at the end?

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 days, public"  and how then do I set the header to Cache-Control? or does that happen automatically by setting ExpiresActive to on ?

Comment: OK, so my first example works, as does ExpiresByType, though with ExpiresByType i'm not sure how to add whether the file type is public or private.

Comment: You need both. (un)fortunately Dave Cheney has done your homework for you :-)