# Where do I put location tag in apache2 configuration file

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I want to put expiration setting similar to mentioned here. [Apache caching with mod_headers mod_expires](https://serverfault.com/questions/15411/apache-caching-with-modheaders-modexpires#answer-15524)

However I am not sure where should I put that code. I am running apach2 on ubuntu and I have 4 vhost in my apache. A vhost config is something similar to this one

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
ServerName xxxxxx
ServerAlias xxxxxxxxxx
DocumentRoot /home/xxxx/current/public
<Directory "/home/xxx/current/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My gut feeling is that I should put  stuff after the end of directory. That would be after this tag . Is that the right place to put the expiration code.

And I am also assuming that I would be repeating the same code for all 4 vhosts. They all need same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it anywhere inside `<VirtualHost>`. So after `<Directory>…</Directory>` is fine, as is before it, or between `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`, etc.

You can probably put it outside the vhost as well, in which case it'll apply to all vhosts (but I'm not completely sure on this).